# How to customize line charts in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, office365, microsoft-excel-365

In an Excel line chart, how do you do the following (if it can be done):

1. have different colours within the line,
2. insert an arrow pointing to an area of the line with a caption
   with text explaining what it is referring to?

Comment: For your #2, just use text boxes and arrows (available in the drawing tools).

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat brute force way to have different colors
within a line in a line chart
is simply to break the data into multiple lines. 
For example, given these data:

[image: a simple line chart]

we can set

- C1 `=IF(ROW()<=3, A1, #N/A)`
- D1 `=IF(AND(ROW()>=3,ROW()<=4), A1, #N/A)`
- E1 `=IF(ROW()>=4, A1, #N/A)`

and get this chart:

[image: same data, broken into three series]

There may be similar tricks,
involving overlaying multiple charts on the same area,
to get other effects, but, offhand, I don’t know of any easy ones.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do any of the two things you want.

Comment: While saying you can't do what you ask is a valid answer, it's necessary to offer a bit of explanation. Further, you're wrong about not being able to do these things, so you'll need to justify your claim.